# Hadoop WordCount Example not working

Tags: exception

I have created one user "hduser", this user my hadoop user

```
hduser@chenna:~$ hadoop fs -mkdir /work1
```

In my "/work" directory I have WordCout.jar and mapredinput.txt

```
hduser@chenna:~$ hadoop fs -ls /work1
```

> WordCout.jar
>   mapredinput.txt

```
hduser@chenna:~$ hadoop jar WorCount.jar com.hadoop.wc.WordCount mapredinput.txt /work2
```

now I got the exception:

> 18/08/15 21:43:25 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1534349563620_0001
>   Exception in thread "main"   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/mapredinput.txt
>       at  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
>       at  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
>       at  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1758)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
>       at com.hadoop.wc.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:66)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess that the WordCount class is expecting an absolute path, which should exist in HDFS. Because you are giving a relative path for mapredinput.txt, the implementation of the class is looking for the file inside the home of the user '/user/hduser'.
You have two options:

- Move your file to /user/hduser
- Change the parameter to the absolute path /work1/mapredinput.txt

Anyway, if the jar is the one taken from the hadoop examples, it most likely that you need to indicate only directories; an input directory where text files should exists and an output directory that shouldn't exist, i. e.:

```
hduser@chenna:~$ hadoop jar WorCount.jar com.hadoop.wc.WordCount /absolute/path/with_files /absolute/path/not_exist
```

One that should work with the configuration you have is:

```
hduser@chenna:~$ hadoop jar WorCount.jar com.hadoop.wc.WordCount /work1 /work1/output1
```

Depends enterely on the implementation of the WordCount class the manner to pass the parameters.